# Retrieving an array of photos from firebase storage

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-storage, ionic4

while i'm working in more than 3 applications using ionic 
every time i face the same issue that is retrieving data from firebase storage

like photos for example

get the downloadURL for one photo works good to be honest but when it comes to get the downloadURL for a lot of photos and make it automatically using *ngFor

its the hardest thing in the world

if you have anything to to this job please help me ill appreciate it

i write this code to do the job

```
export class AdmPage{


  public downloadedUrls: [];


  constructor() {  

    const file = `image/jpg`
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

  var  uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/rivers.jpg').put(file);


    uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
      // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
      // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
      var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
      switch (snapshot.state) {
        case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
          console.log('Upload is paused');
          break;
        case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
          console.log('Upload is running');
          break;
      }
    }, function(error) {
      // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }, function() {
      // Handle successful uploads on complete
      // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
      this.downloadedUrls.push(uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL);

      });

    }
    }
```

and this to show in html

```
 <ion-col *ngFor="let photo of downloadedUrls">
        <img src="{{ photo }}">
     </ion-col>
```

but it doesn't work 
nothing of the photos that i had uploaded in the firebase storage shown

in the chrome console it say this

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [DEFAULT]: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
[DEFAULT]: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
    at app (index.cjs.js:307)
    at Object.serviceNamespace [as storage] (index.cjs.js:366)
    at new AdmPage (adm.page.ts:22)
    at createClass (core.js:22148)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:22029)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:23255)
    at createRootView (core.js:23169)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24177)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:23687...
```

Comment: The error message is suggesting that you didn't integrate the Firebase SDKs correctly.

Comment: but everything with firebase works good even uploading to the firebase and cloud messaging @DougStevenson